# How many @rules in CSS?

Tags: css, import, media

Are there any other recognized @rules besides @import and @media in CSS?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can find a number of @ rules near the top of the specification's [index](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/indexlist.html)